# Returning pipe-delimited data where one element has a 'many' relationship, SQL User-Defined functions

Tags: sql, oracle, user-defined-functions

A quick pre-amble, I've never written a SQL User-Defined function before, so am unfamiliar with it's syntax and what it can do (hence the question).

What I'm trying to do is return a CLOB from the function that looks like something like this:

```
|| fieldDelimiter || DataPoint
|| fieldDelimiter || Datapoint
|| fieldDelimiter || ManyDataPoint,ManyDataPoint,ManyDatapoint
```

So we will have one aspect of the query that returns a primary level of the business object, but then a further part of that query will attach multiple items associated with the primary business object.

This is going to be returned to a Laravel application, and become a Laravel object. I haven't worked with Laravel but I assume the 'ManyDataPoints' might become something like an array in the object.

I'm seeing that these functions use a 'Cursor', and I was wondering if I might need to do something like a nested cursor, but I want to make sure I'm on the right track before I proceed.

Comment: It is generally a bad idea to use CLOBs like that. It sounds like you need a pipelined table function that returns a user-defined table type. That way the columns and rows are real columns and rows that SQL can work with instead of being unstructured data that requires complicated string parsing.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say: Forget the custom response building in Oracle and custom response parsing in Laravel/PHP. Use the built-in XML/JSON building/parsing facilities of Oracle and Laravel/PHP instead for serialization/deserialization of your hierarchical data. I'm pretty sure PHP should already have some of them these days.

Then, just forget about using stored procedures and run the query directly from PHP and fetch the result as a single CLOB. Or, if you want to loop through a cursor in PHP anyway, just remove the master-aggregation part in your query and fetch the serialized children data row-by-row (i.e., master-by-master).

As a side note: With the SQL/XML and SQL/JSON extensions in Oracle DB you have an unlimited control over the structure of the serialized content. Feel free to explore the capabilities yourself in the respective [SQL/XML](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Single-Row-Functions.html#GUID-C64CC0DE-0D7C-42C8-B078-92A2984AD953) and [SQL/JSON](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Single-Row-Functions.html#GUID-C13171B3-C070-4137-AC71-7A30BD26F380) documentation locations.

**Example - Preparation of sample data**

```
/*
drop table t_child purge;
drop table t_master purge;
*/

create table t_master
(
    master_id           integer not null primary key,
    master_name         varchar2(128 char) not null
);

create table t_child
(
    child_id            integer not null primary key,
    master_id           integer not null references t_master (master_id),
    child_name          varchar2(128 char) not null
);

insert into t_master (master_id, master_name) values (1, 'Habsburg Empire');
insert into t_master (master_id, master_name) values (2, 'United Kingdom');

insert into t_child (child_id, master_id, child_name) values (1, 1, 'Slovakia');
insert into t_child (child_id, master_id, child_name) values (2, 1, 'Bohemia');
insert into t_child (child_id, master_id, child_name) values (3, 1, 'Silesia');
insert into t_child (child_id, master_id, child_name) values (4, 1, 'Moravia');
insert into t_child (child_id, master_id, child_name) values (5, 1, 'Austria');
insert into t_child (child_id, master_id, child_name) values (6, 1, 'Hungary');
insert into t_child (child_id, master_id, child_name) values (7, 1, 'Slavonia');
insert into t_child (child_id, master_id, child_name) values (8, 1, 'Transylvania');
insert into t_child (child_id, master_id, child_name) values (9, 1, 'Galicia');
insert into t_child (child_id, master_id, child_name) values (10, 1, '... and some more, I guess');

insert into t_child (child_id, master_id, child_name) values (11, 2, 'England');
insert into t_child (child_id, master_id, child_name) values (12, 2, 'Wales');
insert into t_child (child_id, master_id, child_name) values (13, 2, 'Scotland');
insert into t_child (child_id, master_id, child_name) values (14, 2, 'Northern Ireland');
insert into t_child (child_id, master_id, child_name) values (15, 2, '... and some more, I guess');

commit;
```

**Example - Serialization to XML**

```
with grouped_children as (
    select
        master_id,
        xmlagg(
            xmlelement("country",
                xmlattributes(child_id as "id"),
                child_name
            )
            order by child_id
        ) as children,
        count(1) as number_of_children
    from t_child C
    group by master_id
)
select
    xmlserialize(
        content
        xmlelement("all-data",
            xmlagg(
                xmlelement("empire",
                    xmlattributes(M.master_id as "id"),
                    xmlelement("name", M.master_name),
                    xmlelement("parts",
                        xmlattributes(C.number_of_children as "number-thereof"),
                        C.children
                    )
                )
                order by M.master_id
            )
        )
        indent size = 3
    ) as all_data
from t_master M
    left join grouped_children C
        on C.master_id = M.master_id
;
```

This yields the output of...

```
<all-data>
   <empire id="1">
      <name>Habsburg Empire</name>
      <parts number-thereof="10">
         <country id="1">Slovakia</country>
         <country id="2">Bohemia</country>
         <country id="3">Silesia</country>
         <country id="4">Moravia</country>
         <country id="5">Austria</country>
         <country id="6">Hungary</country>
         <country id="7">Slavonia</country>
         <country id="8">Transylvania</country>
         <country id="9">Galicia</country>
         <country id="10">... and some more, I guess</country>
      </parts>
   </empire>
   <empire id="2">
      <name>United Kingdom</name>
      <parts number-thereof="5">
         <country id="11">England</country>
         <country id="12">Wales</country>
         <country id="13">Scotland</country>
         <country id="14">Northern Ireland</country>
         <country id="15">... and some more, I guess</country>
      </parts>
   </empire>
</all-data>
```

**Example - JSON serialization**

```
with grouped_children as (
    select
        master_id,
        json_arrayagg(
            json_object(
                'partId': child_id,
                'name': child_name
            )
            order by child_id
        ) as children,
        count(1) as number_of_children
    from t_child C
    group by master_id
)
select
    json_serialize(
        json_arrayagg(
            json_object(
                'empireId': M.master_id,
                'name': M.master_name,
                'numberOfParts': C.number_of_children,
                'parts': C.children
            )
            order by M.master_id
        )
        pretty
    ) as all_data
from t_master M
    left join grouped_children C
        on C.master_id = M.master_id
;
```

This yields the output of...

```
[
  {
    "empireId" : 1,
    "name" : "Habsburg Empire",
    "numberOfParts" : 10,
    "parts" :
    [
      {
        "partId" : 1,
        "name" : "Slovakia"
      },
      {
        "partId" : 2,
        "name" : "Bohemia"
      },
      {
        "partId" : 3,
        "name" : "Silesia"
      },
      {
        "partId" : 4,
        "name" : "Moravia"
      },
      {
        "partId" : 5,
        "name" : "Austria"
      },
      {
        "partId" : 6,
        "name" : "Hungary"
      },
      {
        "partId" : 7,
        "name" : "Slavonia"
      },
      {
        "partId" : 8,
        "name" : "Transylvania"
      },
      {
        "partId" : 9,
        "name" : "Galicia"
      },
      {
        "partId" : 10,
        "name" : "... and some more, I guess"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "empireId" : 2,
    "name" : "United Kingdom",
    "numberOfParts" : 5,
    "parts" :
    [
      {
        "partId" : 11,
        "name" : "England"
      },
      {
        "partId" : 12,
        "name" : "Wales"
      },
      {
        "partId" : 13,
        "name" : "Scotland"
      },
      {
        "partId" : 14,
        "name" : "Northern Ireland"
      },
      {
        "partId" : 15,
        "name" : "... and some more, I guess"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: I appreciate the detailed reply. I'm really being thrown into a tier that I haven't touched in nearly a decade, and am not responsible for the PHP app either. So my inclination is to try to just force the solution I've got through, but I'm pretty much on the level of syntax errors at this point.

I'll have to consider stretching this one out to something similar to your solution, it does feel a lot better.